# Adding JTable with custom size

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Games {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;

    public Games() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Games games = new Games();
        games.showTextFieldDemo();
    }

    private void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("The Game Database");
        mainFrame.setSize(1100, 800);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showTextFieldDemo() {

        String[] searchBasis = new String[] { "--Select--", "Genre", "Name of the Game", "Release Year" };

        JLabel lblGenre = new JLabel("Genre", JLabel.RIGHT);
        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel lblReleaseYear = new JLabel("Release Year", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel lblSearchBasis = new JLabel("Search Basis", JLabel.CENTER);

        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
        JComboBox cmbBasis = new JComboBox<>(searchBasis);

        final JTextField txtGenre = new JTextField(12);
        final JTextField txtName = new JTextField(12);
        final JTextField txtReleaseYear = new JTextField(12);
        JTextArea txtContentArea = new JTextArea("hello");

        txtContentArea.setSize(400, 400);

        lblGenre.setEnabled(false);
        txtGenre.setEnabled(false);
        lblName.setEnabled(false);
        txtName.setEnabled(false);
        lblReleaseYear.setEnabled(false);
        txtReleaseYear.setEnabled(false);

        cmbBasis.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (cmbBasis.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Genre")) {
                    lblGenre.setEnabled(true);
                    txtGenre.setEnabled(true);
                    lblName.setEnabled(false);
                    txtName.setEnabled(false);
                    lblReleaseYear.setEnabled(false);
                    txtReleaseYear.setEnabled(false);

                } else if (cmbBasis.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Name of the game")) {
                    lblGenre.setEnabled(false);
                    txtGenre.setEnabled(false);
                    lblName.setEnabled(true);
                    txtName.setEnabled(true);
                    lblReleaseYear.setEnabled(false);
                    txtReleaseYear.setEnabled(false);

                } else if (cmbBasis.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Release Year")) {
                    lblGenre.setEnabled(false);
                    txtGenre.setEnabled(false);
                    lblName.setEnabled(false);
                    txtName.setEnabled(false);
                    lblReleaseYear.setEnabled(true);
                    txtReleaseYear.setEnabled(true);

                } else if (cmbBasis.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("--Select--")) {
                    lblGenre.setEnabled(false);
                    txtGenre.setEnabled(false);
                    lblName.setEnabled(false);
                    txtName.setEnabled(false);
                    lblReleaseYear.setEnabled(false);
                    txtReleaseYear.setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
        });

        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String data = "Genre " + txtGenre.getText();
                data += ", Name: " + new String(txtName.getText());
                statusLabel.setText(data);
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraint.gridx = 0;
        constraint.gridy = 0;
        constraint.insets = new Insets(3, 5, 3, 5);

        controlPanel.add(lblSearchBasis, constraint);
        constraint.gridx++;

        controlPanel.add(cmbBasis, constraint);

        constraint.gridy++;
        constraint.gridx = 0;
        constraint.insets = new Insets(3, 5, 3, 5);

        controlPanel.add(lblGenre, constraint);
        constraint.gridx++;

        controlPanel.add(txtGenre, constraint);
        constraint.gridx++;

        controlPanel.add(lblName, constraint);
        constraint.gridx++;

        controlPanel.add(txtName, constraint);
        constraint.gridx++;

        controlPanel.add(lblReleaseYear, constraint);
        constraint.gridx++;

        controlPanel.add(txtReleaseYear, constraint);
        constraint.gridx++;

        controlPanel.add(btnSearch, constraint);

        constraint.gridy++;
        constraint.gridy++;
        constraint.gridx = 0;
        constraint.insets = new Insets(3, 5, 3, 5);

        controlPanel.add(txtContentArea, constraint);
        mainFrame.pack();

        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I have the above code, all I need is a custom sized 3 column JTable below these 3 textfields so I can populate my data there. I have tried many ways but didn't get much from that... they all are static in size.. kindly help me out. Thanks.

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) `JTextArea txtContentArea = new JTextArea("hello");

    txtContentArea.setSize(400, 400);` Better to suggest a size in columns and rows. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). This problem, for example, seems to be everything to do with layouts & component sizes & nothing to do with whether or not labels are enabled.

Comment: txtContentArea can be removed, its just for a test. & all the fields are disabled they can be enabled by selecting the values from the combo box above brother.

Comment: *"txtContentArea can be removed"* Oh good, so **remove it!** (Rather than suggest other people wade through the code to figure out what is and is not relevant to this layout problem.) Also note you would not have had to explain that the enabled state of labels was irrelevant if they were similarly removed.

Comment: Override [`getpreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjtable%5d%20getpreferredScrollableViewportSize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all I need is a custom sized 3 column JTable

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Setting and Changing Column Widths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width) for information on this.

Once you have set the column widths you can then use:

table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

To set the preferred size of the JTable and its scroll pane.

```
mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
```

Don't use a WindowListener to close the frame.

Instead you can just set a property of the `JFrame` when you create the frame:

```
mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
```